# How do I write a Rails finder method through a chain of belongs_to associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, associations, belongs-to, finder

I'm using Rails 5.1.  How do I write a finder method when there is a chain of "belongs_to" associations?  I have the following models ...

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
    ...
  has_many :plan_items, :dependent => :destroy


class PlanItem < ApplicationRecord
    ...
  belongs_to :offer, :optional => false


class Offer < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :package, :optional => false


class Package < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
```

I want to write a finder that gets all Plans with an Item with id = "blah".  But the below is failing ...

```
[19] pry(main)> Plan.joins(plan_items: :offer).joins(packages: :item).where(:item => {:id => "abac"}).count
ActiveRecord::ConfigurationError: Can't join 'Plan' to association named 'packages'; perhaps you misspelled it?
from /Users/davea/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.1/gems/activerecord-5.2.2.1/lib/active_record/associations/join_dependency.rb:188:in `find_reflection'
```

How do I write a finder when there is a chain of belongs_to associations?

Comment: How do your migrations look like?

Comment: Hey @SebastianPalma!  Glad to see you on the thread.  I will try and dig those up.  Pardon my asking, but why are the migrations important?  Is it possible to construct a finder based on the information given?

Comment: With that, it's easier (at least for me) to create a sample application where to test and elaborate an answer for this case.

Comment: Ok sure let me see what I can do here.

Answer (score 1):

First, maybe your table name is wrong. Second, to pass method between `belong_to` association, you can use delegate

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming `PlanItem` is a join table between `Plan` and `Item` (that would be inline with the Rails naming convention).  This could be done neatly with `through` associations and scopes.  I would do it like this...

```
class Plan < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :plan_items, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :plan_items

  scope :blah_items { items.id_of_blah }

class PlanItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :offer, optional: false
  belongs_to :item

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  scope :id_of_blah { where(id: 'blah') }
```

Then you can call it like so... `Plan.with_blah_items` or if you had an active record collection of plans you could use the scope to narrow it down `plans.with_blah_items`.

Since ActiveRecord associations will return ActiveRecord relations, you can chain them with any other active record methods (e.g. `Plan.first.items.where(item: { id: 'blah' })`  Scopes just make it nice and neat. : )

If `PlanItem` is *not* a join table between Plan and Item, first thing you should do is rename it.  This is not just a best practice, rails spends a lot of time assuming what things are named, and it could cause a bug.  After you rename it you should create a join table between Plan and Item called `PlanItem`.  If a join between these tables doesn't make sense with your application architecture, you could always string `through` associations together, but that would be a code smell.

If you didn't want to mess with scopes, you could always just do a query like this `plan.items.where(items: { id: 'blah' })`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: PlanItem isn't a join table -- it has a column "offer_id".  Is there any way to write a finder query without adding the additional "through" associations you specify above?

Comment: You could have a class method on `Plan` that just ran a query and returned the plans you wanted.  That would be basically your query above, but I think you missed the tense of your association.  As the error tells you, you put 'packages' instead of 'package' as the association is defined.  `Plan.joins(plan_items: { offer: { package: :items } }).where(items: { id: 'blah })` should get you what you're after, but is definitely not the ideal solution.